# Disabling MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN

Tags: mariadb

How to I disabling the MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN option on MariaDB ?
I tried to comment the `#export LIBMYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN=y`unsuccessfully..

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

`MYSQL_ENABLE_CLEARTEXT_PLUGIN` environment variable is supported by MySQL only. MariaDB Connector/C and client utilities use the clear_text plugin on demand, which means if the server requested clear_text plugin for authentication. It can't be disabled.

The clear_text plugin is used for PAM authentication only and sends the password, or token unencrypted. The solution is either to specify the dialog plugin for authentication or to use a TLS connection.

See also [mysql_clear_password](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/authentication-plugin-pam/#mysql_clear_password)